# Webservice with CXF: How to use the ResponseWrapper?

Tags: java, web-services, response, wrapper, cxf

We are creating a webservice (CXF-based) driven by a java class (Java2WS) with the following method:

```
  @WebMethod
  @RequestWrapper(className = "com.myproject.wrapper.MyRequestWrapper")
  @ResponseWrapper(className = "com.myproject.wrapper.MyResponseWrapper")
  public MyResponse verifyCode(@WebParam(name = "code") String code) {
    ...
    return new MyResponse("Hello",StatusEnum.okay);
  }
```

I use the wrappers to define the elements of the request resp. response in more detail: the correct element names (which start with an uppercase character), required and optional elements, ...). But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it (there is no in-depth documentation about wrappers, isn't it?)

The class MyResponse:

```
public class MyResponseWrapper {

  private String result;   
  private ModeEnum status;

  // getters and setters
}
```

The class MyReponseWrapper

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myResponse")
public class MyResponseWrapper {

  @XmlElement(name="Result")
  private String result;

  @XmlElement(name = "Status")
  private StatusEnum status;

  public MyResponseWrapper() {
    result="fu"; // just for testing
  }

  // getters and setters
}
```

Currently I don't understand the Wrappers. When I return an instance of MyReponse, how does the data from MyResponse be injected into MyResponseWrapper respectivly to the SOAP body of the response?

By testing this webservice I can see that an instance of MyResponseWrapper is instantiated and the SOAP body contains the correct elements but with default data (for example: result="fu" instead of "Hello"). I expected that CXF injects matching data from MyResponse to MyResponseWrapper. Is that wrong?

If this is the wrong way to do it:
Wat is the right way to specify the resulting SOAP xml when using Java2WS?

By the way: The above source snippets are just examples taken from our more complex (more fields) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do it.
The request and response wrappers just allow for overriding the xml namespace and element/attribute names for the request/response elements; respectively - which in turn map to the methods used to manage those values.

Ref: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-The@RequestWrapperannotation

> The @RequestWrapper annotation is defined by the
>   javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper interface. It is placed on the methods in
>   the SEI. As the name implies, @RequestWrapper specifies the Java class
>   that implements the wrapper bean for the method parameters that are
>   included in the request message sent in a remote invocation. It is
>   also used to specify the element names, and namespaces, used by the
>   runtime when marshalling and unmarshalling the request messages.
>
> The following table describes the properties of the @RequestWrapper
>   annotation.
>
> localName
>
> Specifies the local name of the wrapper element in the XML
>   representation of the request message. The default value is the name
>   of the method or the value of the @WebMethod annotation's
>   operationName property.
>
> targetNamespace
>
> Specifies the namespace under which the XML wrapper element is
>   defined. The default value is the target namespace of the SEI.
>
> className
>
> Specifies the full name of the Java class that implements the wrapper
>   element.

Comment: className property has package name different to the class . Eventhough the full Name is different , webclient is working . What could be the reason??  Example: @WebMethod
  @RequestWrapper(className = "myproject.com.wrapper.MyRequestWrapper")
  @ResponseWrapper(className = "myproject.com.wrapper.MyResponseWrapper")
  public MyResponse verifyCode(@WebParam(name = "code") String code) {
    ...
    return new MyResponse("Hello",StatusEnum.okay);
  }

Comment: Many frameworks like Spring or any aspect-oriented-programming (AOP) platform use JVM injection techniques to 'point' a wrapper class to the original and back again such as when creating a "join point". ORM frameworks like Hibernate do the same. This link shows an example of getting the 'actual' className in a log for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505735/log4j-and-aop-how-to-get-actual-class-name