# Log4j and AOP, how to get actual class name

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-aop

I'm implementing a logger as an aspect using Spring AOP and Log4J, but I've noticed that the class name in log file is always the `LoggerAspect` class name, so... is there a way to trace the actual class name in my log?

Comment: Can you make it part of the message itself?

Comment: See also: [Spring: Standard Logging aspect (interceptor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@Around("execution(* com.mycontrollerpackage.*.*(..))")
public Object aroundWebMethodE(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {      
    String packageName = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
    String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(!pjp.getSignature().getName().equals("initBinder")) {
       logger.info("Entering method [" + packageName + "." + methodName +  "]");
    }
    Object output = pjp.proceed();
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    if(!methodName.equals("initBinder")) {
       logger.info("Exiting method [" + packageName + "." + methodName + "]; exec time (ms): " + elapsedTime);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This even works for proxied classes (the non-proxied name is shown in the log message).

Answer (score 13):

this is easier:

```
pjp.getTarget().getClass()
```

Comment: But one problem ProceedingJoinPoint is only supported for around advice only not for Before or After

Answer (score 4):

**Use** : `pjp.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Also, to add logs at class level of which method is being exexuted instead using logger of advice class, use class level logger within advice method, as below

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(pjp.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

Comment: This is not a good practice i.e. asking for logger object for every advice method call.

Comment: Good point @Mohit, but Slf4J has an implementation of having all the logger objects cached, so it's not a significant overhead.